# How can I enable Power View in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, performancepoint, powerview

I use `SharePoint 2013` and `Performance Point Service` for create `Business Intelligence` report.

I need more functionality in report generate.

I found that `Power View` in this scenario can help me but I do not know `How I can install and configure Power View` in `SharePoint 2013`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable Power View for SharePoint by installing and configuring the Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint 2013. There is a good guide for installing and configuring the BI features of SharePoint 2013 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/querysimon/archive/2012/11/26/installing-the-bi-features-of-sharepoint-2013.aspx). If you already have BI features on your SharePoint farm, [here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615462/Configure-Power-View-Reporting-Services-Features-o) how to configure Power View.

Basically, you need to:

- Install SQL Server 2012 SP1 CTP3
- Uninstall Report Services - Native if you have installed it
- Install Reporting Services – SharePoint & Reporting Services Add-In for SharePoint Product
- Install Analysis Services In Tabular Mode and Data Tools Install SharePoint Reporting Service
- Install and Configure Power Pivot for SharePoint
- Configure Performance Point Services
- Configure Reporting Services
- Check SharePoint Power Pivot Integration

Be aware that the data source for Power View must be a Power Pivot model, SSAS Tabular Model, or SSAS Multidimensional model (Power View for SharePoint only, must have SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU4).